# Need help developing SQL to find difference in date

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-help

I am attempting to write a query that will take a date value and return a numerical value. What I plan to use this for is to track the days until an inspection is due. For example I will input the inspection expiration date into the database, then I want the query to return the value of days remaining until the inspection is due.

 

Thanks for the help. I am not that good with SQL. I know how to write basic queries but anything past that I really don't know what to do.

Comment: Pick a platform please. MySQL or SQL Server? Read the tag wikis - they are not the same thing.

Comment: sorry about that I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `timestampdiff()` function to get the remaining days.

Lets say the expire date is `2014-10-31` and comparing with now you can get the days as

```
mysql> select timestampdiff(day,now(),'2014-10-31') as days ;
+------+
| days |
+------+
|   11 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```